# OSB fn-bea functions using Xquery processor in Java

Tags: xquery, osb

Hi i am trying to unit test xqueries that are used in OSB ,using  oracle's Xquery processor for java . refer link below

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqj.htm#ADXDK187

The Xquery is using some fn-bea functions (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13167_01/aldsp/docs25/xquery/extensions.html)

The functions are not recognized by the Xquery Processor .

We are thing of desclaring these functions as external Functions and use them .

However we need to know the exact class and method name for each bea function .

Can some tell me the Class and method names for these fn-bea functions and the jar names .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fn-bea module is not intended for use in the standalone XQuery Processor for Java.  You can import the module as shown below but some of the functions will not work in this context.

```
import module namespace fn-bea = 'http://www.bea.com/xquery/xquery-functions';
fn-bea:trim('  hello  ')
```

There is no guarantee that this module will be available in future releases.

Comment: Hello, I m using saxon and this solution not works for me. can you help me?