# Using OSB fuction bea in java xquery processor

Tags: java, xquery, transformation, osb, bea

For my transformation i'm using `org.apache.xmlbeans`

(`xmlObject.execQuery(xqueryFileContent, options);`)

Now I come up with an issue that somehow fn-bea functions are not working:
in this example: `fn-bea:uuid()`

The stacktrace:

```
Caused by: weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryStaticException: line 15, column 18: {err}XQ0017: "{http://www.bea.com/xquery/xquery-functions}uuid": unknown function (or number of arguments (0) is wrong)
```

I've read a thread where they say it's not supported, but this isn't satisfying.

**How can I grant my java processor access to the bea functions?**

**EDIT:**
The XQuery at line 15:

```
    <bp-id>{replace(fn-bea:uuid(), '-', '')}</bp-id>
```

the declaration:

```
declare namespace fn-bea ="http://www.bea.com/xquery/xquery-functions";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable most of the fn-bea functions using the Oracle XQuery Processor for Java:
[OSB fn-bea functions using Xquery processor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142547/osb-fn-bea-functions-using-xquery-processor-in-java)

But as you noticed, this is not supported and it will not enable several of the fn-bea functions including fn-bea:uuid().

You could implement your own external function:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqj.htm#GUID-4B1AD5F7-FAF2-44C3-B577-5A5CF44B5AFF